# Delete an App's data when it is uninstalled in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am new to iOS development, Now I am creating an app that will store contact information to address book from the app. (This app will store your friend's contact details like mobile number and email etc. on your address book when he/she installed the same app on their iPhone and accepted you as their friend).

The app contact is differentiated to native contacts by putting a note property as app name.

My question is, When you uninstall/delete the app it clear all data except contacts which are stored by the app itself. So How to delete the contacts too?
App target platform is, iOS 5 & later & xCode version 4.5.2
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't. If your app saves contact to the user's iPhone contacts, there is no way of deleting them when your app gets deleted.

Comment: Scott thanks for your quick (lightning fast) reply. Even when I put the note property as app name, still isn't possible?. Also Is there any built in method/function called during uninstalling/deleting the app and extended to developers to add their code?

Comment: Nope. You will have to accept that your app may be uninstalled at any point, without you ever knowing it.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately there are the occasional annoyances when developing for a closed platform like iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect app deletion. So there is no way to delete your data before deletion. So answer is no.